# generating every possible letter and number combination 8 and 63 characters long. in bash

Tags: bash

How would a generate every possible letter and number combination into a word list something kind of like "seq -w 0000000000-9999999999 > word-list.txt" or like "echo {a..z}{0..9}{Z..A}", but I need to include letters and length options. Any help? And side info, this will be run on a GTX980 so it won't be too slow, but I am worried about the storage issue, If you have any solutions please let me know.

Comment: no matter how you want to access `word-list.txt` there is a better way to get that data. If you tell us what you'd like to do with that file we might be able to help. Also, you're right to be worried about the storage, that would be >100 billion times the amount of data on the internet.

Comment: uh it is for ethical brute force attacks.

Comment: Man, there are `(2 * 26 + 10) ^ 63` 63-character-long strings. That's 8.33 times ten to the 112th power. You're not gonna store all of that.

Answer (score 1):

file1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo \#!/bin/bash > file2.sh
for i in $(seq $1 $2)
do
  echo -n 'echo ' >> file2.sh
  for x in $(seq 1 $i)
  do
    echo -n {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,\
             A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,\
             0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} >> file2.sh
  done
  echo
done
```

I don't think it's a good idea, but this ought to generate a file which when executed will generate all possible alphanumeric sequences with lengths between the first and second arguments inclusive. Please don't actually try it for 8 through 64, I'm not sure what will happen but there's no way it will work. Sequences of the same length will be space separated, sequences of different lengths will be separated by newlines. You can send it through `tr` if you want to replace the spaces with newlines. I haven't tested it and I clearly didn't bother with silly things like input validation, but it seems about right.

If you're doing brute force testing, there should be no need to save every combination somewhere, given how easy and (comparatively) quick it is to generate on the fly. You might also consider looking at one of the many large password files that's available on the internet.

P.S. You should try doing the math to figure out approximately how much you would have to spend on 1TB hard drives to store the file you wanted.